# Weird character in front of Highcharts tooltip series names

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart which is, for some reason, showing odd characters before the series title only on the data point pop up.  I am using the default popup and highcharts 4.0.1.

I currently set all series to have the title `hi` to ensure nothing in my code was messing this up.  Also if I output `countsGraph.series[0].name` I also get `hi`.

What is causing this? Unfortunately I cannot make a fiddle at the moment as my access to HighCharts.com is playing up.

Here is how I create the series

```
// Create new series if requried
if (!series[c]) {
    series[c] = {
        name: "hi",
        data: []
    };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably you are using different coding than UTF-8. You can simply remove that character, by changing [`pointFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat), from:

```
<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>
```

to:

```
<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>
```

Or, as just `@Adam Goodwin` pointed out, set default format in your options:

```
<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>
```

Comment: My page meta is set to `<meta charset="utf-8" />` - what else would I need to do?

Comment: Set encoding of the files in your IDE. `a-` is representation in CP-1250.

Comment: Good idea, but I changed the file (highcharts) to UTF-8 without BOM via Notepad and it still didnt work

Comment: OK so I added a new PointFormat as you suggested which works, still v odd why it happens at all.  Thanks for your help though

Comment: Hard to guess.. maybe you have saved file for Highcharts and encoding was cahnged? Are you using our CDN?

Comment: awesome...thanks for the answer...it worked for me...the issue i had was that if i run it as a stand alone html, it works...but if i deploy it in tomcat, i get that special character...now with the pointFormat in place, those characters disappeared...

Comment: I had this problem too, what is weird is that I was able to fix it by explicitly setting the `pointFormat` to the default value – i.e. the one *with* the `\u25CF` character.

Comment: It's probably caused by fact your file is in different encoding. When you put this directly in that file, later browser will encode this with the same format and result may be satisfying. But that's a good point!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Encoding in Notepad++ was set to 'UTF-8 without BOM'. When I switched it to 'UTF-8' it fixed it. Thanks!

UPDATE - that had some undesirable effects on other stuff, so I ended up adding to the html:

> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" / >

and that fixed it all

Answer (score -1):

the simple solution to all the problem is using a tooptip

code is as follow:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
    shared: true
},
series: {
    code here 
}
```

workable and easy solution to remove the weird character on hover on highcharts.