# Highcharts - a with hat in tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have a code that generates charts dynamically based on the users inputs. I do not specifically format the tooltip, I just allow the defaults to take control. For some reason, there is consistently an a with a hat over it in the tooltip. For example, when hovering over a column chart entry, the tooltip shows:

Category
a(hat)- Series name:Value

Any idea where this ahat is coming into play?

Comment: Looks like an "unprintable character" - could you dump the string you created as hex bytes to see what is in it? I suspect some Unicode crept on.

Comment: I don't actually create the string, it is done through some default method.

Comment: Can you get to the string and print it as hex bytes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert these strange characters? (Ã«, Ã, Ã¬, Ã¹, Ã)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127744/how-to-convert-these-strange-characters-%c3%83-%c3%83-%c3%83%c2%ac-%c3%83%c2%b9-%c3%83)

Comment: The "duplicate" I marked is obviously a different question but I believe that the information given in that question / answer is directly pertinent to the question you ask here, and without more information I don't think you will get a better "answer".

Comment: And this is direct duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012451/weird-character-in-front-of-highcharts-tooltip-series-names

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I understand the encoding issue, what I need to know is where Highcharts is introducing this mistake as I am using all default settings and not formatting the tooltip myself.

Comment: Just read my answer.. it's introduced in default `pointFormat`.

Comment: Thanks Pawel Fus for the answer. Is there a way to close this question or have you answer it so that I can select that answer without causing a problem?

Comment: I won't because it's duplicate and answer would be the same.